# Two Monster Digamma series with closed form?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

I am looking for a proof of the following two results:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}\left[\psi\left(\frac{n+5}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{n+3}{4}\right)\right]=\frac{\log^22}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{24}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\left[\psi\left(\frac{2n+5}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{2n+3}{4}\right)\right]=2G-\frac{\pi}{2}\log2$$
I got them as corollaries after evaluating some integrals, but I wonder if they can be obtained in other ways.
Looking at the two sums, my guess is *no*, or at least not easily, since those digamma functions look very scary. They can be reduced to $$\psi\left(1+\frac{f(n)+1}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac12+\frac{f(n)+1}{4}\right)$$ where $f(n)$ is $n$ in the first sum, and $2n$ in the second. However, this doesn't seem to lead to some simplifications. How would you proceed?

**EDIT**

There is also the more beautiful result
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}\left[\psi(2+n)-\psi\left(\frac{3}{2}+n\right)\right]=\frac{3\log^22}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{24}$$

Comment: There is something totally wrong in my "answer". I prefer to delete it and rework. Sorry about it :-(

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici no worries, I hope you will share in the future a revisited version of it :-)

Answer (score 2):

The second series can be computed using some formulas of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's [GR] *Table of Integrals, Series, and Products (7th Edition)*. First, we get rid of the digamma functions:
\begin{align}
\psi\left(\frac{2n+5}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{2n+3}{4}\right)
=2\beta\left(\frac{2n+3}{2}\right) \tag{GR 8.365.2} \\
=2\int_0^1\frac{t^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}{1+t}\,dt. \tag{GR 8.371.1}
\end{align}
Then, substituting the above identity in the series and interchanging the order of integration and summation, we obtain
\begin{align}
S_2&=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\int_0^1\frac{t^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}{1+t}\,dt \\
&=2\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+t}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(\sqrt{t})^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\right)dt \\
&=2\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(\sqrt{t})}{1+t}\,dt \tag{GR 1.643.1} \\
&=4\int_0^1\frac{x\arctan x}{1+x^2}\,dx \\
&=4\left(\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x}{x}\,dx -\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x}{x(1+x^2)}\,dx\right) \\
&=4\left[G-\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\log 2 + \frac{1}{2}G\right) \right] \tag{GR 4.531.1/7} \\
&=2G-\frac{\pi}{2}\log 2.
\end{align}

Comment: Appreciate it. Is the document you mentioned free online? Seems like a good tool to use